# Kendo grid virtual scrolling broken/not fetching data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am a beginner working on Kendo Grid. I wanted to load the data on demand in the grid, like :

I set the page size to 10, when a user scrolls down to 10 rows, the 
grid should retrieve next 10 rows from database and display it on 
demand.To do this, I changed "scrollable: true" to "scrollable: {virtual: true}". But this disables scrolling in the grid.

```js
$scope.source = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  batch: true,
  group: getDSGroup(),
  transport: {
    read: userSvc.getUserList,
    update: _dataUpdateItem
  },
  error: function(e) {
    ngDialog.openConfirm({
      template: 'httpErrorDialogId',
      className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
      data: {
        'status': e.status,
        'message': e.errorThrown
      }
    });
  },
  schema: {
    parse: function(data) {
      $rootScope.$log.log("User list was fetched.");
      if ($rootScope.sysSettings.userMgr_serverPaging)
        return data;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
        data.items[i].letter = data.items[i].lastName.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        if (data.items[i].departmentName == null) data.items[i].departmentName = $rootScope.$translate.instant("Unassigned");
        if (data.items[i].userGroupName == null) data.items[i].userGroupName = $rootScope.$translate.instant("Unassigned");
      }
      return data;
    },
    model: {
      id: "id"
    },
    groups: "groups",
    total: "totalItems",
    data: "items"
  },
  filter: getDSFilter(),
  sort: getDSSort(),
  pageSize: $rootScope.sysSettings.userMgr_serverPaging ? 10 : 0,
  serverGrouping: $rootScope.sysSettings.userMgr_serverPaging,
  serverPaging: true,
  serverSorting: $rootScope.sysSettings.userMgr_serverPaging,
  serverFiltering: $rootScope.sysSettings.userMgr_serverPaging
});

$scope.userListOptions = {
  //sortable: true,
  groupable: true,
  selectable: false,
  //pageable: true,

  scrollable: {
    virtual: true
  },
  //dataBound: function() {
  //  this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
  //},
  columns: [{
    field: "firstName",
    template: kendo.template($("#tpl-UserItem").html())

  }, {
    field: "letter",
    hidden: true,
    groupHeaderTemplate: "#= value #"
  }]
};

$scope.isEndlessScroll = function() {
  return $rootScope.sysSettings.userMgr_serverPaging;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your grid is is being created while is invisible, the connfiguration is a bit diffrent.

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/grid/walkthrough#initializing-the-grid-inside-a-hidden-container

hope this help

Comment: No, I am not creating the Grid while its invisible, neither have used any hidden fields. Similar code is being used in other grids as well and they all work fine @Marco Palma